# Are there events raised when system clock changes?

Tags: datetime, xamarin, event-listener

Using DateTime.Now I can get the current time.  I can get updated times using a timer by continuously checking the DateTime.Now at intervals using seconds or milliseconds.  So I can make a label and simulate a live clock.  I've got that.

But, is there a way that I can catch an event when the minutes or hours change on the clock, without having to use a timer and get the current time every x number of seconds?  So, when the minute changes is there an event raised by DateTime or some other property?

Or is using a timer and checking every second the only way to find out when the minute changes, using DateTime.Now?

Answer (score 2):

You would need to use platform dependent code (i.e. via a dependency service to setup a callback event would work well).

On Android, you can register an `BroadcastReceiver` for `Intent.ActionTimeChanged` (and `Intent.ActionTimezoneChanged` if needed):

```
[BroadcastReceiver]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionTimeChanged })]
public class TimeChanged : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Time change, do something with that knowledge");
    }
}
```

On iOS, you can register for a `NSSystemClockDidChange` notification:

```
NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(new NSString("NSSystemClockDidChangeNotification"), (obj) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Time change, do something with that knowledge");
});
```