# Does NSSystemClockDidChangeNotification receive notification on automatic timezone updates(without manual intervention.eg when the user is travelin)?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin

Can we detect timezone changes by the phone versus a user specifically changing the time?
Same question for android as well..where I am using intent.ActionTimeChanged ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement this on each platform (iOS / Android) separately.

On Android, you can register an `BroadcastReceiver` for `Intent.ActionTimeChanged` (and `Intent.ActionTimezoneChanged` if needed):

```
[BroadcastReceiver]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionTimeChanged })]
public class TimeChanged : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Time change, do something with that knowledge");
    }
}
```

On iOS, you can register for a `NSSystemClockDidChange` notification:

```
NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(new NSString("NSSystemClockDidChangeNotification"), (obj) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Time change, do something with that knowledge");
});
```

I test the solution on my side ,it works fine .

Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/56141207/8187800 .

Comment: With NSSystemClockDidChange (iOS) and intent.ActionTimeChanged(android) the notification is received whenever the user changes date/ time manually. However, will this notification also be received when the 'system' changes the time via time zone change when a person is travelling to a different time zone for example ? if that is the case then is there a way to ignore that event..so that only the manual time changes done by a user can be captured?

Comment: Yes, i think the event is only triggered with manual time changes done by a user .